# PHP Array: Loop Array until the value is empty

Tags: php, arrays

So, I build a little php array looping.
The objective is : the loop will finish when one of array value is empty.

This is the code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $Var_1 = array('Manggo_1' => rand(1, 3),
                  'Manggo_2' => rand(1, 3),
                  'Manggo_3' => rand(1, 3),
                  'Manggo_4' => rand(1, 3),
                  'Manggo_5' => rand(1, 3),
                  'Manggo_6' => rand(1, 3)
                );

   $Var_2 = array('Manggo_7' => rand(1, 3),
                  'Manggo_8' => rand(1, 3),
                  'Manggo_9' => rand(1, 3),
                  'Manggo_10' => rand(1, 3),
                  'Manggo_11' => rand(1, 3),
                  'Manggo_12' => rand(1, 3)
                 );



  while (!(empty($Var_1) && empty($Var_2))) {


      foreach ($Var_1 as $value) {
            echo "$value, ";
            if ($value == 3) {
                unset($value);
            } elseif ($value == 1) {
                array_push($Var2, $value);
            }
      }

      foreach ($Var_2 as $value) {
            echo "$value, ";
            if ($value == 3) {
                unset($value);
            } elseif ($value == 1) {
                array_push($Var1, $value);
            }
      }
  }
}
```

So, that's all my php code, If the `$value == 3`, I want to destroy the value, and `if == 1`, I want to insert the value to another array. Loop until one of array is empty.

The question is: How to print/echo the result from each loop iteration (after click the submit button), until one of the array value is empty ?? 
I always get looping forever.

Thanks.

Comment: you'd have to assign by reference in foreach: `foreach ($Var_1 as &$value)`, now you can unset the actual array-item! have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1):

```
 while (!empty($Var_1) && !empty($Var_2)) {


  foreach ($Var_1 as $key=>$value) {
        echo "$value, ";
        if ($value == 3) {
            unset($Var_1[$key]);
        } elseif ($value == 1) {
            array_push($Var_2, $value);
        }
  }

  foreach ($Var_2 as $value) {
        echo "$value, ";
        if ($value == 3) {
            unset($Var_2[$key]);
        } elseif ($value == 1) {
            array_push($Var_1, $value);
        }
  }
}
}
```

> You are getting looping forever because

1. The condition in while loop is not correct .(according to your condition 
   the loop will finish only after both the array become empty.)
2. Problem in unsetting the array variable.
3. You are pushing values into wrong variables .

Answer (score 0):

You aren't unsettling the value from the array, you are just unsetting a local variable within the loop. You can use $key=>$value to obtain a reference back to the looped array like so:

```
foreach ($Var_2 as $key=>$value) {
        echo "$value, ";
        if ($value == 3) {
            unset($Var_2[$key]);
        } elseif ($value == 1) {
            array_push($Var1, $value);
        }
  }
```